# Get subnet of an interface in bash for ip route

Tags: sed, regular-expression, iproute

From the `ip addr` command I get a subnet address of the type `192.168.0.1/24` but the `ip route` command needs a subnet adress of the type `192.168.0.0/24`.

If I try using `sed -E 's/(?<=\d.)1(?=\/)/0/g'` to change the last "1" to "0", I get the error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Invalid preceding regular expression`

Comment: You have some PCRE syntax, that sed doesn't support, is my guess.

Comment: Try `ip -4 -br a s` for easier ip grepping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that sed doesn't support PCRE syntax. Try this GNU sed snippet:

```
sed -r 's:([0-9]\.)[0-9]{1,3}/:\10/:g'
```

If `-r` isn't accepted, use `-E`.

Comment: I updated it to translate the Perl regex from your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Perl instead of sed because sed doesn't support lookaheads and lookbehinds as @seshoumara pointed out.

```
ip -o -f inet addr show eth0 | awk '/scope global/ {print $4}' | perl -ne 's/(?<=\d.)\d{1,3}(?=\/)/0/g; print;'
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that doesn't give you the actual subnet (it doesnt return the network address).    it just replaces `.1` with `.0` - for a subnet that doesn't have a network address of `.0` you'd get very wrong data......